# NEO4jClient GraphClient.Connect() exception thrown

Tags: neo4j, neo4jclient

I am noew to Neo4jClient and I have just tried to get a simple project up and running.

I installed Neo4jClient through the NUGET Package Manger and the console said to me that everything had installed correctly.

I opened a new blank console app and tried the following:

```
GraphClient GC = new GraphClient(new Uri("http://localhost:7474/db/data"));
GC.Connect();
```

Only for it to throw the following exception on execution.

Received an exception when executing the request.

```
The exception was: Array cannot be null.
Parameter name: bytes System.ArgumentNullException: Array cannot be null.
Parameter name: bytes
at System.Text.Encoding.GetString(Byte[] bytes)
at RestSharp.Extensions.MiscExtensions.AsString(Byte[] buffer)
at RestSharp.RestResponseBase.get_Content()
at RestSharp.Deserializers.XmlDeserializer.Deserialize[T](RestResponse response)
at RestSharp.RestClient.Deserialize[T](IRestRequest request, RestResponse raw)
```

Anyone got any idea why this null exception is being thrown ??

Comment: Does http://localhost:7474/db/data open ok in a browser for you? What does it show?

Comment: Do you still have node 0 in the database?

Comment: Resolved the server was not not running correctly. A restart fixed it.

Comment: @TathamOddie what it must show? How can check localhost:7474/db/data is open? if it show the root its means it's open?